# list() method from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

While developing the backend for a web app, we used hibernate to handle the database. So, while testing, we had a test failing.

```
package com.app.db.hibernate.test;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.app.db.hibernate.UserManager;
import com.app.db.utils.TestUtils;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class HibernateUserTest {

    public final UserManager um = new UserManager();
    public Integer id;
    public HashMap<String, Object> userParams;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this.userParams = TestUtils.loadParams();
        this.id = this.um.agregar(this.userParams);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteUserTest(){
        //Se elimina el usuario de la db:
        um.deleteUser(userParams);
        //Se comprueba que no esta:
        Integer id_ = um.search(userParams);
        assertNull(id_);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp(){
        um.reset();
    }
}
```

So here we add a user to the database, call the `deleteUser()` method, and check if it works (`search(userParams)` should return `null`). The thing is that the test fails since, even though `um.deleteUser(userParams)` deletes the dummy user from the database, `um.search(userParams)` still "finds" it (by returning the id of the user just deleted, I checked that by debugging the code), I do not know from where, thus failing. Here's the code for `delete()` and `search()`:

```
public void deleteUser(HashMap<String, Object> params){
    Session sesion = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try{
        sesion.beginTransaction();
        User u = (User)sesion.get(User.class, search(params));
        sesion.delete(u);
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        he.printStackTrace();
    }finally{sesion.close();}
}

public Integer search(HashMap<String, Object> params) {
    Session sesion = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Integer id = null;
    try{
        List lista = sesion.createCriteria(User.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("name",(String)params.get("name"))).list();
        if(lista.size() == 1){id = ((User)lista.get(0)).getId();}
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        he.printStackTrace();
    }finally{sesion.close();}
    return id;
}
```

`reset()` just cleans the users table:

```
public void reset() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("delete from User");
    q.executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

So, my question is: Is there something i'm missing here to make the test pass? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I solved it. I forgot to get the transaction from the session and commit it in the `search()` method; that made the test pass at least. But anyway, if there's anything you might add to improve this code, you can share it as well :)

Comment: If you have found a solution, it is not only permitted, but encouraged, to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the trick was to add some lines, to get the transaction from the session, and commiting, to go from this:

```
public Integer search(HashMap<String, Object> params) {
    Session sesion = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Integer id = null;
    try{
        List lista = sesion.createCriteria(User.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("name",(String)params.get("name"))).list();
        if(lista.size() == 1){id = ((User)lista.get(0)).getId();}
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        he.printStackTrace();
    }finally{sesion.close();}
    return id;
}
```

to this:

```
public Integer search(HashMap<String, Object> params) {
    Session sesion = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Integer id = null;
    //get the transaction object:
    Transaction tx = sesion.beginTransaction();
    try{
        //a new restriction added to the search:
        Criteria criteria = sesion.createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", (String)params.get("name")));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email", (String)params.get("email")));
        List lista = criteria.list();
        //commit:
        tx.commit();
        //only one should be found, this is yet to be implemented:
        if(lista.size() == 1){id = ((User)lista.get(0)).getId();}
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        //in case of an exception thrown while committing, roll back transaction:
        tx.rollback();
        he.printStackTrace();
    }finally{sesion.close();}
    return id;
}
```

That made the test pass :)